# "helps making", "helps make", "helps to make" - what is the difference?

Tags: infinitives, gerunds, sentence-choice, to-infinitive

For the three sentences below:

> Good horizontal spacing **helps make** individual statements more readable.

> Good horizontal spacing **helps to make** individual statements more readable.

> Good horizontal spacing **helps making** individual statements more readable.

Is one of them preferable to the others? If so, please justify. Are any of them incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this source:](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/gerunds-and-infinitives-verbs-1.html)

> 'help' can also be followed by the infinitive without 'to' with no difference in meaning: 'I helped to carry it' = 'I helped carry it

It [further says](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/gerunds-and-infinitives-verbs-2.html) that 'help + 'ing'' is possible but then the pattern is 'can't help'.

Example follows

> *He **can't help talking** so loudly.*

Comment: +1, but I want to note that *can't help* is an idiom with a special meaning: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/can%27t_help

Answer (score 1):

The verb construction was to help to do. Nowadays to help + infinitive is felt something similar to a modal verb and to help is usually followed by a bare infinitive.
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/help_1?q=help